# Moving a partion to disk "/" with gparted

Tags: 13.04, partitioning, 13.10, gparted

Ok so I was trying to update my ubuntu 13.4 to ubuntu 13.10 but I kept getting I didn't have enough free space on disk "/" so I got gparted and I have 134 gb how could I move some space from there to disk "/" so I could update

[image: http://i1374.photobucket.com/albums/ag433/joseruiz10/Screenshotfrom2013-11-27204542_zps38c8f4e9.png]

Comment: how much space did you want to move from `/dev/sda3` to `/dev/sda5`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Boot gparted live cd or Ubuntu live cd.
- If you boot ubuntu live cd then run the following commands to install gparted,

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gparted
  sudo gparted
  ```
- After gparted opened,right click on the /dev/sda3 and click on the Resize option,and free up the space you want to add to the `/` partition.
- The freedup unallocated space comes under the `/dev/sda3` partition.
- then right  click on the `extended partition`,select the `Resize` option and add the unallocated space to it.The unallocated space comes under the `/dev/sda7`.
- Right click on the `/dev/sda5` probably `/`partition and select the `Resize` option,now you can add the unallocated space to the `/` partition.

Comment: Thanks but i am unable to resize the extended partition, when i right click ,resize is unhighlighted

Comment: u can't able to resize a mounted partition,see the image lock key shows that the partition is mounted.

Comment: unmount is also not highlighted

Comment: you are logged into `/` partition that is ubuntu,so you can't unmount it.plz run gparted live disk or ubuntu live disk.

Comment: i am running ubuntu on a netbook so unfortunately i cant run the live disks .Would there by any other way

Comment: try `live-usb`.

Comment: how would i try live-usb ?

Comment: did you can able to boot from usb?

Comment: sorry for me being a newbie on all of this but how would i boot from an ubuntu live usb

Comment: did you have ubuntu.iso file?If yes then follow this http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu